# Character Conversion Still Not RIght (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, character

FIrst, thanks to all who responded to my first two questions.  I have tried what was suggested and still nothing works.  I thought I would create another post with the code that I am using.  Just for some background:  I am creating a guessing game for my son and I need to change characters form character to decimal to character.  I have added the code and the logs.  I hope this is more helpful.

```
-(IBAction)CHANGE:(id)sender
NSString    *working_text;
NSInteger   working_text_length;
NSInteger   new_key_char_num;
NSInteger   key_char_num;
NSInteger   key_char_position = 0;
NSInteger   char_num = 0;
NSString    *altered_text;

working_text = UITextView_1.text; 
working_text_length = working_text.length;
altered_text = @"";
UITextView_1.text = @"";

int k = 0;
while (k < working_text_length)
{
char_num = [working_text characterAtIndex:k];           
key_char_num        = 65;
new_key_char_num    = char_num  + key_char_num;
    UITextView_1.text = [UITextView_1.text   
    stringByAppendingFormat:@"%c",new_key_char_num];   



    NSLog(@"char_num................%c",char_num);
    NSLog(@"char_num................%d",char_num);
    NSLog(@"key_char_num........... %d",key_char_num);
    NSLog(@"new_key_char_num........%d",new_key_char_num);
    NSLog(@"new_key_char_num........%c",new_key_char_num);
    NSLog(@" ");

    char_num = 0;
    k++;
}


 NSLog(@"UITextView_1.text full text...%@",UITextView_1.text);
 NSLog(@"first  %c",[UITextView_1.text characterAtIndex:0]);
 NSLog(@"second %c",[UITextView_1.text characterAtIndex:1]);
 NSLog(@"third  %c",[UITextView_1.text characterAtIndex:2]);


 // release code is not shown


}
```

LOGS

```
2009-10-04 22:43:04.949 DaVinci SMS[20757:20b] char_num................A
2009-10-04 22:43:04.951 DaVinci SMS[20757:20b] char_num................65
2009-10-04 22:43:04.951 DaVinci SMS[20757:20b] key_char_num........... 65
2009-10-04 22:43:04.952 DaVinci SMS[20757:20b] new_key_char_num........130
2009-10-04 22:43:04.953 DaVinci SMS[20757:20b] new_key_char_num........Ç
2009-10-04 22:43:04.953 DaVinci SMS[20757:20b]  
2009-10-04 22:43:04.954 DaVinci SMS[20757:20b] char_num................B
2009-10-04 22:43:04.955 DaVinci SMS[20757:20b] char_num................66
2009-10-04 22:43:04.956 DaVinci SMS[20757:20b] key_char_num........... 65
2009-10-04 22:43:04.956 DaVinci SMS[20757:20b] new_key_char_num........131
2009-10-04 22:43:04.957 DaVinci SMS[20757:20b] new_key_char_num........É
2009-10-04 22:43:04.957 DaVinci SMS[20757:20b]  
2009-10-04 22:43:04.958 DaVinci SMS[20757:20b] char_num................C
2009-10-04 22:43:04.959 DaVinci SMS[20757:20b] char_num................67
2009-10-04 22:43:04.959 DaVinci SMS[20757:20b] key_char_num........... 65
2009-10-04 22:43:04.960 DaVinci SMS[20757:20b] new_key_char_num........132
2009-10-04 22:43:04.960 DaVinci SMS[20757:20b] new_key_char_num........Ñ
2009-10-04 22:43:04.961 DaVinci SMS[20757:20b]  
2009-10-04 22:43:04.961 DaVinci SMS[20757:20b] UITextView_1.text...ÇÉÑ
2009-10-04 22:43:04.962 DaVinci SMS[20757:20b] first  «
2009-10-04 22:43:04.962 DaVinci SMS[20757:20b] second …
2009-10-04 22:43:04.963 DaVinci SMS[20757:20b] third  —
```

I entered the characters 'ABC' in the UITextView.  I am just using three characters for now.   If you notice at the bottome og the log the complete UITextView_1.text string is not equal to the individual characters that I pull using the characterAtIndex method.  This is driving me crazy.

Comment: Some extra things: One should use the `unichar` typedef and the `%C` format specifier for characters grabbed from an NSString.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go from char to integer and back, no need to add anything - you can simply treat the unichar as an integer:

```
NSString *s = @"ABC";
unichar c = [s characterAtIndex: 0];
NSLog(@"char code: %i, char: %c", c, c); // output: char code: 65, char: A
```

Comment: The adding of 65 to char_num is not required.